# validation File size constraint from value in configuration file

Tags: php, validation, constraints, assert, symfony-2.8

I'm using the default assert File :

```
/**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\File(
     *  mimeTypes={
     *          "application/pdf",
     *          "image/jpeg",
     *          "image/pjpeg",
     *          
     *  },
     *  mimeTypesMessage="The file format is not correct",
     *  maxSize="1M",
     * )

     * @var File $file
     */
    private $file;
```

I verify if the file size is less the 1M . But what if i want to create a configuration in a config file like:

```
//yml file
max_size_file : 1
```

and use the value in the assertion.

I know that is need to create a custom validation as service and inject the container to get the config value from the parameters or config file .it 's seems something like  :

```
/**
  *
  *@Assert\myConstraint()
  */
private $file
```

any help please .

Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution :

first let's make a config value in the parameter file :

```
//parameters.yml

max_file_size_upload: 2 // the unit is MEGABYTE
```

> the unit value is MB , so check the factorizeSize methd in  FileSizeValidator if you wanna custom your own logic

To implement a custom validator , symfony offer you to create a class for the constraint and to other one for the validation of the constraint , so let's first create the constraint class:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AppBundleBundle\Service\Validation;


use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

    /**
     * the Max file size upload constraint
     *
     * @Annotation
     * Class FileSize
     * @package Acme\AppBundle\Service\Validation

     */
    class FileSize extends Constraint
    {
        /**
         * @var string the message error if the file {{size}} uploaded is greater than {{limit}}
         *
         * {{size}} the file upload size
         * {{limit}} max_file_size_upload in the parameters.(env).yml
         *
         * in case of custom the error message, add the maxSizeMessage attribute the the assertion :
         * @example :
         *
         *           maxSizeMessage= "you custom message ({{ size }} ). you custom message  {{ limit }} ."
         *
         */
        public $maxSizeMessage = 'The file is too large ({{ size }} M). Allowed maximum size is {{ limit }} M.';


    }
```

the validator class of the constraint :

```
<?php


namespace Acme\AppBundle\Service\Validation;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;

    /** 
     *
     * Class FileSizeValidator
     * @package Acme\AppBundle\Service\Validation
     */
    class FileSizeValidator extends ConstraintValidator
    {

        const CONVERT_MB_TO_B = "MBTOB";
        const CONVERT_B_TO_MB = "BTOMB";


        private $_maxFileSizeUpload;


        public function __construct($maxFileSizeUpload)
        {
            $this->_maxFileSizeUpload = $maxFileSizeUpload;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $value
         * @param Constraint $constraint
         */
        public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
        {

            if (!$constraint instanceof FileSize) {

                throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, __NAMESPACE__.'\FileSize');
            }

            if($value instanceof UploadedFile){

                if($this->_maxFileSizeUpload < $this->factorizeSize($value->getClientSize())){

                    $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->maxSizeMessage)
                        ->setParameter('{{ size }}', $this->factorizeSize($value->getClientSize(),self::CONVERT_B_TO_MB))
                        ->setParameter('{{ limit }}', $this->_maxFileSizeUpload)
                        ->addViolation();

                }

            }

            return;

        }


        /**
         * @param $size
         * @param string $convert
         * @return float|int
         */
        protected function factorizeSize($size,$convert =self::CONVERT_MB_TO_B){

            $size = intval($size);

            if($convert == self::CONVERT_MB_TO_B){

                return $size*pow(10,6);

            }
            else{

                return intval($size/pow(10,6));

            }


        }




    }
```

The validator should be declared as service to inject the parameter value , so we need to add it in the service.yml :

```
  fileSizeValidator.service:
    class: Acme\AppBundle\Service\Validation\FileSizeValidator
    arguments: [%max_file_size_upload%]
    tags:
      - name: validator.constraint_validator
        alias: file_size_correct
```

> The alias : file_size_correct is the value tha your method validateBy
>   sould return in the FileSize Class , because your Validator is now
>   service  , if not , your constraint can't find the Validator class .
>   see the official doc [here][1]
>
> [1]:
>   https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies

use the constraint :

```
   /**
     * @MyAssert\FileSize()
     *
     * @var File $file
     */
    protected $file;
```

hope this help you .